# EasyMock capture throws NullPointerException

Tags: java, junit, mocking, easymock

I suddenly stumbled upon an issue that I need to capture a parameter of this interface called:

```
public interface MyInterface {

    void doSomething(long id);
}
```

```
@Mock
private MyInterface myInterface;

...

Capture<Long> capturedId = Capture.newInstance();
myInterface.doSomething(capture(capturedId));
```

The test failed quite early:

> ```
> java.lang.NullPointerException
>   at com.mycompany.MyInterfaceTest.doSomethingTest(MyInterfaceTest.java:81)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>   at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
>   at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
> ```

I triple-checked that no way a `null` is passed, what is going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is the implementation of the [`EasyMock#capture(Capture<T>)`](https://easymock.org/api/org/easymock/EasyMock.html#capture-org.easymock.Capture-) method that always returns `null`:

```
public static <T> T capture(final Capture<T> captured) {
    reportMatcher(new Captures<T>(captured));
    return null;
}
```

This would not be a problem if the mocked method would accept an object type `Long` as a parameter:

```
void doSomething(long id);
```

... however, the `long` primitive type is present and the attempt of unboxing the return value (`null`) of the [`EasyMock#capture(Capture<T>)`](https://easymock.org/api/org/easymock/EasyMock.html#capture-org.easymock.Capture-) method fails on `NullPointerException`.

The fix is simple: For this reason, there were introduced method variations suitable for primitive types, such as [`EasyMock#captureLong(Capture<Long>)`](https://easymock.org/api/org/easymock/EasyMock.html#captureLong-org.easymock.Capture-):

```
myInterface.doSomething(captureLong(capturedId));
```